# I want to send image size of bytes from javascript to controller in byte[] using ajax call in MVC Core controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I am uploading an image file to  .net MVC controller using javascript and AJAX POST call. But the problem is--

1) I am getting size of file in javscript using  this
`var FileSize = $('#ProfilePicUpload')[0].files[0].size;`

When I send it to controller it doesnot receive any data in byte datatype. Instead it goes either in string or int or long datatype.

1)I've used jquery to get the size of image using `files[0].size`. I successfully get the size of uploaded image.

2)I also set `content-type: 'application-json/UTF-8'`. and `processData:false` and `contentType:false`. 
But this results in string[] OfficialData to 0 on controller side.

3)I am receving rest of form data in string[] on controller side and only image size in byte[] format

```
//OfficialData.js file

    var FileSize = $('#ProfilePicUpload')[0].files[0].size; //get size of image file.

        //ajax call
        $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "/Employee/AddEmployeeOfficialDetail",
                  data: { "OfficialData": Employee_Data, size: FileSize },
                  success: function (data) {
                     if (data.check === -1) {
                     jAlert("Employee Already Exists!", "Alert", function () {});}

        //controller code
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddEmployeeOfficialDetail(string[] OfficialData,byte[] size)
        {
        Employee.fileContents.FileSize = BitConverter.GetBytes(size);
        }
```

`I get byte[] size = null`
`If I use int then I get size of image File like int size = 34598.`

My only requirement is to get exactly the size of Image from java-script from ajax call to byte[] on controller side.

Comment: Why are you trying to use a byte array for a single number value? If you want an array you need to send an array, meaning you would have to break apart your size value into its high/low order bytes manually on the client side. Or change the type to int and do the operation on the servr

Comment: What is the value of `FileSize` when you `console.log` it?

Comment: @mjwills it gets as `FileSize = 20857`..It's different for different files..but I get like this when I `console.log` it

Comment: Have you tried `int size` instead?

Comment: @PatrickEvans I want byte array because I want to store it in azure blob storage..and over there it's asks content in byte[] only..that's where I'm stucked!

Comment: @mjwills yes.. I tried `int` as well as `long`.. Here is the controller code `public async Task<IActionResult> AddEmployeeOfficialDetail(string[] OfficialData,int size)`   Now when I convert this using this `Employee.fileContents.FileSize = BitConverter.GetBytes(size);`  here I get `byte[]` but when I upload in azure storage image is damaged...

Comment: Why are you using `string[]` for an image?

Comment: i think you are looking at the documentation wrong. Are you sure it isnt saying to store the actual file data in a byte array

Comment: @mjwills it contains other data from form...in javascript array like      `var Employee_Data = {};
    Employee_Data[0] = EmployeeCode;`